# Why does pattern matching not compile with JToken

Tags: c#, json.net

```
JToken jToken = JToken.Parse("{ \"meta\": { \"status\": 200 } }");
if (jToken.SelectToken("meta.status") is long status)
    Console.WriteLine("It's a boy!");
```

gives compile error:
`CS8121 An expression of type 'JToken' cannot be handled by a pattern of type 'long'.`

but this compiles without error:

```
JToken jToken = JToken.Parse("{ \"meta\": { \"status\": 200 } }");
if ((long)jToken.SelectToken("meta.status") is long status)
    Console.WriteLine("It's a boy!");
```

[dotnet issue 16195](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/16195) indicates that pattern matching should work if an explicit conversion exists, so what am I missing?

I'm testing with [Newtonsoft.Json 12.0.3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/12.0.3) and in:
Visual Studio 16.7.7 (C# 7.3 as per `#error version`)
Visual Studio 15.9.28 (C# 7.1 set in project properties)

Edit: This appears to be a more robust way of doing the test, but I still don't understand why I have to tell C# the JToken is a long before it will test if it's a long.

```
JToken jToken = JToken.Parse("{ \"meta\": { \"status\": 200 } }");
if (jToken.SelectToken("meta.status")?.Value<long>() is long status)
    Console.WriteLine("It's a boy!");
```

Comment: [Docs](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_op_Explicit_3.htm) say that there is an explicit conversion from `JToken` to `Nullable<long>`, not to `long`

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski thanks. I'm not sure I understand the wording of the C# spec, but it seems weird that a JToken can be cast to a "long?", but C# can't tell me if it's a long or not!